# How to inverse column and row in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How can I inverse my data in Redshift from

| user_id | type1 | type2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | false |
| 2 | true | false |

to

| user_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 | true |
| 1 | type2 | false |
| 2 | type1 | true |
| 2 | type2 | false |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a union all:

```sql
SELECT user_id, 'type1' AS type, type1 AS value FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 'type2', type2 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY user_id, type;
```